UK SIPP allowance
If I have 10k of rental income and 10k of earnings from employment? What is the maximum amount I can pay into a SIPP?
I assume this would be 8000 and (plus SIPP automatically reclaim 20% income tax, hence adding 25% to the amount contributed) so paid 100% of earnings into pension.
However if you look at the personal allowance, the total amount of income tax paid is less than £2000. (£1700 ish in fact). Is this okay?

Minor point on wording - you are not claiming 25% tax. You are effectively paying in £10,000 of which £2,000 is paid by the government, this is a tax rate of 20% of £10,000 not 25% of £8,000. There is no 25% income tax rate in the UK at the moment.

Yes I know. will update to reflect this.
